# Install an updated version of a WPF application that I created in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a WPF application in C#, let's call it MyApp v1.0 and I installed it on a machine. Now, I have a newer version, MyApp v1.1 that I want to install on the same machine that would automatically replace it with MyApp v1.1. this MyApp application installs with its installation a database which it uses to store and retrieve its data. this data is critical and I don't want the database to be replaced everytime I install an updated version. I just want the new version to replace the old version and if the database schema is changed in the new version then to modify the old schema but without messing around with the stored data. this application is written in C#. I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look into [ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which supports deployment of a SQL CE database. There are issues which are covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340534/upgrading-sql-ce-via-clickonce-update).

Other options include:

- [Visual Studio Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c.aspx)
- [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)
- [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm) (commercial)

Comment: well actually I'm using WIX to install my application and create the MSI file. So I don't know how to do the update